# how to reset raspbian password? change in "cmdline.txt" did not work

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have raspberry pi3 model B with raspbian OS version 2016.
I forgot user and password for login.
I have made change in cmdline.txt in micro SD card and add init=/bin/sh
but nothing happened and when boot OS agian request Login user name and password!

Could you please guide me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `cmdline.txt`? It sounds like the change was not successful.

Comment: Would be nice to have a "migrate vote", as this question might be relevant on superuser but not a programming question for here.

Comment: True. Best we have is "flag" as "should be closed".

Comment: @HeathRaftery No it has done. I checked it again in my PC after second boot of raspberry